# Get path from parent URL (current window URL) in ajax call looped inside another ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a php page (client.php) contains the script below. The script performs an ajax call. Upon success, it executes another ajax call. I'm having an issue with the second ajax call where it returns the `request_uri` as "sql/adminloademail.php" not the parent path which is "/client.php". How do I tell php to echo the parent path "/client.php" which appears in the current window URL?

**SCRIPT**

```
$.ajax({
  method:'POST',
  url:'sql/adminaddclient.php',
  data:formData,
  contentType: false,
  processData: false,
  success: function(data){
    $.ajax({
      type:'POST',
      url:'sql/adminloademail.php',
      success: function(data){
        $('#account_list').html(data);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

**PHP(adminloademail.php)**

```
$page = parse_url(filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'REQUEST_URI' , FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING), PHP_URL_PATH);
echo $page;
```

Comment: You're not being very clear here, the part after the domain isn't `/client.php`, but `/admin-add-client.php`, those are hyphens ?

Comment: adeneo please see my changes for further clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set parent url to a variable and then send it with the data param.

```
var parentUrl = window.location.href;

$.ajax({
  type:'POST',
  url:'sql/adminaddclient.php',
  data:formData,
  contentType: false,
  processData: false,
  success: function(data){
    $.ajax({
      type:'POST',
      data:{"parentUrl":parentUrl},
      url:'sql/adminloademail.php',
      success: function(data){
        $('#account_list').html(data);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Also you can try to get it from headers.

```
$headers = apache_request_headers();
if (isset($headers['Referer'])) {
    echo "Referer: " . $headers['Referer'];
}
```

Since PHP 5.4.0 `apache_request_headers` also available under FastCGI.

Since PHP 5.5.7 `apache_request_headers` also available in the CLI server.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.apache-request-headers.php

Comment: Thanks! This works. But is there a way to do it with pure php? It seems strange that this is one of php limitation in 2017.

Comment: @ninjachuku You can try to check the Referer. I have updated the answer.

Comment: @ninjachuku It may be. JS method is more reliable.

Comment: Agreed. Thanks Talgat.

Comment: @ninjachuku Don't forget to check existence of the parentUrl in $_POST.